# AngularJs add animation to ng-swipe

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, swipe, angular-ui

i'm facing a real challenge here :)
Adding animation to ng-swipe operation,
i have line that i'm swapping, i want it to slide-left or slide-right then the new
line will be appear instead,
currently it is showing like on/off switch it just dissapear.

Do i need to create directive? can i use only css?
Can you help with an example
I was searching over the net and haven't found anything helpful.
Thanks

```
div.add-to-favorite-open(ng-show="showActions && item.is_favorite==false",ng-swipe-left="showActions = false",data-ng-click='add_pro_to_favorite(item); showActions=!showActions')
                        div.add-to-favorite-image
                        p.add-to-favorite-text Add to Favs
div.remove-from-favorite-open(ng-show="showActions && item.is_favorite==true",ng-swipe-left="showActions = false",data-ng-click='remove_from_favorite(item); showActions=!showActions')
                        div.add-to-favorite-image
                        p.add-to-favorite-text Remove from Favs     
div.contact-slide(ng-show="!showActions",ng-swipe-left="showActions = true")
```

Comment: did you found the solution to this?? I too am in need of the solution .

Comment: sorry i didn't find a solution for that.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do something like this;

http://onehungrymind.com/demos/slider-touch/

Check how using  in Angular 1.2 here;

http://onehungrymind.com/build-sweet-angularjs-photo-slider-pt-2-ngtouch/

Another tutorial here;

http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/366/index.html#